# Reduce unwanted "connect to network" attempts with wireless password

Tags: wireless-networking

My university recently added a 5-digit (WEP) network password to their wireless network. (This is in addition to a login page that requires university credentials.) I emailed them, and they said the purpose of the new password was to reduce "connect to network" attempts by unauthorized users that was impacting the wireless bandwidth. I don't understand this explanation. Any help?

Comment: Hmmm....this question has already been asked elsewhere on either this or another SE why are you repeating yourself???

Comment: @mdpc - Yes, I asked this question on ServerFault, but it was closed because they don't like questions from "end users or enthusiasts."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me get this clear...to connect to the network..

**New Path**

Device -> Enter WEP -> Browse to Login Page -> Now Connected.

**Old Path** (Assuming no wireless key at all)

Device -> Browse to Login Page -> Now Connected

> From comments: If the system doesn't have a 'too many bad passwords' countermeasure, a 5 digit PIN code would be extremely simple to crack. If it does, then the network simply refuses connections from a certain computer for x minutes after y number of bad password guesses. –  Michael Frank

--

The **'New Path'** provides a way to reduce wasted bandwidth by thwarting unwanted/unauthorized visitors. Those visitors never get to send requests to the actual network, they can only send a 'few' packets to the wireless router for authentication. They never get to actually join the network, thus saving bandwidth.

The **'Old Path'** provides an unwanted/unauthorized visitor an open network connection, then forces them to interact with a server via a web browser. This would allow anyone who may not even have true access to the University network to view this page in the browser while on the network. Each view/request of the page results in bandwidth being used, if the person was never supposed to be on the wireless network in the first place then that is wasted bandwidth.

Comment: But then isn't the login-page redundant?  If the student has the WEP password, why should the network waste bandwidth re-authenticating them?

Comment: @Tiberia If the system doesn't have a 'too many bad passwords' countermeasure, a 5 digit PIN code would be extremely simple to crack. If it does, then the network simply refuses connections from a certain computer for `x` minutes after `y` number of bad password guesses.

Answer (score 2):

Without WEP: Computer connects to network successfully, is redirected to the log in page and then proceeds to supply the required credentials. This method allows the computer to completely connect to the wireless network, but doesn't allow internet access if they fail at the log in stage.

With WEP: Computer asks to connect to the wireless, the wireless replies with "What's the password?", and if your computer can't supply the correct password then the connection attempt is denied.

However, the network may not monitor unsuccessful connection attempts which would allow a user to simply brute force the 5-digit PIN fairly quickly, thus gaining access the same way as before.

Comment: Re "With WEP" - Correct, but they publicize the password to all their students.  And it's [literally the code I have on my luggage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JNGI1dI-e8), not hard at all to crack.

Comment: "they publicize the password to all their students" - The idea is that students have the password to gain access, but the general public have to spend `x` minutes brute forcing the WEP system.